# git pull when a tracking branch is ahead and behind by some commits

Tags: git, github, git-pull

Let's say I have a tracking branch on my local repository and I've made a couple of commits.

At the same time my tracking branch is behind a couple of commits from the remote branch that it is tracking.

So, if I do git pull does the merge happen or do I get an error? 
If yes, then do I get a merge commit resulting from the two branch tips and a common ancestor?

Would have tried it out but thought I'll just ask if anyone knows.

Thanks :)

Comment: Don't know the answer but do tell once you have tried it.Like to know about it.

Comment: `git pull` means *run `git fetch` and then run a second Git command.* The second command is `git merge` by default, but you can tell Git to use `git rebase` instead. The main tricky part with `git pull` is getting any arguments you give it correct (and in the bad old days of Git 1.5-1.8 or so, various bug-cases under which `git pull` could lose your work or otherwise behave badly). I prefer to do the two commands separately, some of which is habit from those bad old days.

Comment: I also thought it's better to use `git fetch` and `git merge` instead. I couldn't understand the outcome in this use scenario for `git pull`, I think I'll have to try it. Thanks for sharing about the `git rebase` option. Didn't know about that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do `git pull`, git will try the 3-way merge with your local branch, the remote one and their common ancestor, precisely as you asked. If the merge fails, you have to solve the conflicts manually.

You need to do `git pull`, sooner or later. If you try `git push` before doing that, you get an error, as long as your local branch is behind from the remote branch.

Comment: Okay, I'll get an error if I get a merge conflict and if not then the three way merge should happen? I feel it's just safer to do `git fetch` and then merge yourself. I don't know if I want to try this.

Comment: Well, `git pull`is just `git fetch`+ `git merge`, so it would be the same.

Comment: Exactly what I'm saying. I feel `git pull` will just mess up the merges.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error once your local branch is behind the remote, you could try stashing your recent commit then you do a git-pull and merge. You could later apply the stashed commit

Comment: and then you can create a new branch for the remote branch and merge it with the local branch. Why would git throw an error?